# How do I highlight text with button highlights?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-linearlayout, android-button

I have a navigation drawer in my code. The navigation drawer has buttons which allow to navigate through the app.Now when I click on the button just the button Highlights.What I expect is the button to highlight along with the text and when I pull out nav drawer again it shows me the last button text highlighted until I click on another button which highlights upon click and stays highlighted until another selection is made.Here's my code for the same:

```
public class NavigationPanelFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    public static final String TAG_NAVIGATION_PANEL_FRAGMENT = "NavigationPanelFragment";
    public static final String ACTIVE_MENU_ITEM = "ActiveMenuItem";
    public final static String activeFragmentTitle = "";
    public static void newInstance(final FragmentManager manager, final String activeFragmentTag) {
        final NavigationPanelFragment fragment = new NavigationPanelFragment();
        final Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(NavigationPanelFragment.ACTIVE_MENU_ITEM, activeFragmentTag);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        final FragmentInfo fragmentInfo = new FragmentInfo(TransactionMethods.ADD);
        fragmentInfo.setAnimation(R.anim.slide_in_from_left, FragmentInfo.NO_ANIMATION);
        fragmentInfo.setPopAnimation(0, R.anim.slide_out_to_left);
        fragmentInfo.setFragmentTag(TAG_NAVIGATION_PANEL_FRAGMENT);
        fragmentInfo.doNotAddToBackStack();
        fragmentInfo.setActionBarTitle(Application.getAppResources().getString(R.string.title_applications));
        FragmentStackManager.getInstance().transitionFragment(manager, fragment, fragmentInfo);
    }
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    highlightActiveMenuItem();
}
    private void highlightActiveMenuItem() {
        TextView highlightedTextView = null;
        //getArguments().getString(ACTIVE_MENU_ITEM);
        final Resources resources = Application.getAppResources();

        if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_news).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_news);
            
        } else if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_markets).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_markets);
            
        } else if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_lists).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_lists);
        } else if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_alerts).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_alerts);
        }
        else if (resources.getString(R.string.nav_option_briefcase).equals(activeFragmentTitle)) {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_briefcase);
        } else {
            highlightedTextView = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.nav_option_dashboard);
        }

        highlightedTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_orange));

    }
```

Corresponding xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.justin.a"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_texture"
    android:clickable="true" >
    
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/nav_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/nav_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/nav_margin"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/nav_margin"
    android:background="#242424"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/nav_padding"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_padding"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/nav_padding"
        
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_bright"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:showDividers="middle"
                            
             >

         
             <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_dashboard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                android:onClick="onDashboardClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_dashboard"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"
                    />  
            <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_news"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                android:onClick="onNewsClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_news"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"
                
                 />

            <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_markets"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                android:onClick="onMarketClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_markets" 
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"

                />

            <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_lists"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_lists"
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:onClick="onListsClicked"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"

               />

            
            <com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
                android:id="@+id/nav_option_briefcase"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_ht"
                android:textSize="@dimen/navigation_panel_text"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1px"
                foo:customFont="cabin.medium.ttf"
                android:padding="@dimen/nav_option_padding"
                android:onClick="onBriefcaseClicked"
                android:text="@string/nav_option_briefcase" 
                android:background="@drawable/nav_background_button"

                
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]
For clearing the confusion, in plain words, suppose I open the navigation drawer , the dashboard is highlighted (orange highlight) by default, then I click on say markets, it opens up the markets screen and by requirement I would need the market button text to be highlighted instead of dashboard, but it doesn't do the same and keeps the dashboard highlighted all along.Before navigation drawer I used to use a simple navigation panel, in that I used to have
activeFragmentTitle =getArguments().getString(ACTIVE_MENU_ITEM); (refer to the java code, its commented out now in the code ) , but then it caused crash after I added nav drawer ,and hence I had to comment it out and make activeFragmenttile = ""; as you can see from the java code above, how do I get the previous line of code into the code such that there's no crash and i attain the required objective?

Comment: I keep seing around that of FragmentStackManager and FragmentInfo, but i dont know what it is...

Comment: It's very difficult to see what's going on with the class and layout you've provided. Can you illustrate the problem with a screenshot?

Comment: Hi guys, I added a screenshot and better explanation with the screenshot, please check it out

Comment: Where do you call highlightActiveMenuItem()? I don't see it getting called anywhere. Please post that section of code as well so we can troubleshoot that.

Comment: I call it in onActivityCreated() method, I added that block in the question for reference

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried extending a CheckedTextView instead TextView ?

```
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/nav_option_something"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/selector"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:textColor="@drawable/selector_to_highlight_the_text"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

and here is the selector_to_highlight_the_text.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white_text"/>
<item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@color/white_text"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white_text"/>
<item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/black_text"/>
<item android:color="@color/black_text"/>
```

Comment: I want the text to stay highlighted until a new selection is made , and based on my code

Comment: there must be a way of getting this line to work activeFragmentTitle =getArguments().getString(ACTIVE_MENU_ITEM); without any crashes, just cant find out how

Answer (score 0):

Just mention the text Color attribute with the below selector( `text_selector.xml`) in  all `com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView`.

Like:

```
<com.justin.a.utils.FontTextView
 android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
<--other attributes-->
/>
```

text_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/dark_orange"></item>
<item android:state_selected="false" android:color="@android:color/white"></item>

</selector>
```

In code just replace the Line:

```
 highlightedTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_orange));
```

with:

```
highlightedTextView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:state_pressed="true">        
          <shape 
   android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="7dp">

 <solid android:color="#F4886C"/> 
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>

 <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>  
    </item>    
    <item android:state_pressed="false">        
           <shape 
   android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="7dp">

 <solid android:color="#E43D12"/> 
    <corners
     android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>

 <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
     </item>

 </selector>
```